# Mock Illuminate Config facade without Laravel

Tags: testing, laravel-5, phpunit, mockery, laravel-facade

I'm working on a package that relies on the `Config` facade.
The code itself works fine, but I'm encountering issues when testing.

Initially, I was using this code:

```
Config::shouldReceive('foo.bar')
    ->andReturn(true);
```

As many [others](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4072), I bumped into some issues.

I later read that mocking the `Config` facade [isn't encouraged](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking#mocking-facades).

To get around it, most people tend to suggest to use the following instead:

```
Config::set('foo.bar', true);
```

Which I reckon works fine, if you're testing from Laravel/Lumen.

But my issue is, I'm not. I just rely on a few `Illuminate` packages, so that won't work since I get:
`RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.`

At this point, some might suggest that I should just inject the `Config` repository dependency, but I'm using the `Config` facade in a trait which is used by an `Eloquent` model, so DI won't work.

Is there any other way  I can tackle this?

Thanks!

**PS:** This question has also been posted on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/mock-illuminate-config-facade-without-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those running into a similar issue, I've finally found the correct way to address this problem.

Testing Laravel packages is just what the [Testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) package is for.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench#usage):

> To use Testbench Component, all you need to do is extend `Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase` instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.

This way, setting a configuration value is just a matter of calling `Config::set()` as you would on a full Laravel install. No more `Mockery` issues.

Answer (score 1):

I faced to the same issue. Lumen 5.4
using `Config::set('key', 'value')` was not worked. So I had to use this way.

```
//test
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

Config::shouldReceive('get')
                    ->once()
                    ->with('key')
                    ->andReturn('value');
```

,

```
//code
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

Config::get('key'); //instead config('key');
```

Comment: Your issue isn't related to mine. You're using Lumen, which still has most of the `Illuminate` packages, so the `Config::set()` should work as long as you enable Facades in the `bootstrap/app.php`. My use case is for testing a Laravel/Lumen package in a standalone environment, where you don't have an entire framework at your disposal, so you have to rely on Testbench. Also, as stated in the documentation, mocking the `Config` isn't a best practice. Hence, the downvote.